# Is it possible to pass the result of a function as input into two functions in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have the function `generate-code` that runs in a `while` loop in Clojure:

```
; ...
(with-local-vars [code nil]
    (while true
        (var-set code (generate-code @code))
        (write-to-file @code)
        (execute-code @code)))
```

Obviously this isn't very Clojure-esque - is there a better way to do this without introducing local variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for `let`:

```
(let [code (generate-code)]
    (write-to-file code)
    (execute-code code))
```

You could also

```
((fn [code] 
    (write-to-file code)
    (execute-code code))
 (generate-code))
```

Or, if you wanted

```
(last ((juxt write-to-file execute-code) (generate-code)))
```